# Least upper bound/greatest lower bound property

Tags: real-analysis

Determine which of the following sets have the least upper bound property
and which have the greatest lower bound property.

(a) $S = (-\infty, 1) \cup [2, 3) \cup (3, 10]$

(b) $S = (-\infty, 1) \cup [2, 3) \cup [3, 10]$

(c) $S = (-\infty, 1) \cup [2, 3) \cup [9, 10]$

I am thinking each of the sets has the least upper bound property, but not the greatest lower bound property because each set is bounded above by 10 and bounded below by -infinity. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let's review some definitions:

A set *S* of real numbers is called *bounded from above* if there is a real number *k* such that *k* ≥ *s* for all *s* in *S*. The number *k* is called an *upper bound* of *S*. The terms *bounded from below* and *lower bound* are similarly defined.

The *supremum* of a subset *S* of a totally or partially ordered set *T* is the least element of *T* that is greater than or equal to all elements of *S*. Consequently, the *supremum* is also referred to as the *least upper bound*. The *infimum* or *greatest lower bound* is similarly defined.

*completeness of the real numbers* asserts every nonempty subset of the set of real numbers that is bounded above has a supremum that is also a real number.

In our given problems, the set *T* in the supremum definition is ℝ. To be bounded above, each set *S*, do we have a number *k* ≥ for all *s* in *S*? Sure. It's 10. So it is bounded above and by completeness, it has a supremum that is also a real number. So your intuition about having the greatest upper bound property is correct. Now what is the least element of ℝ that is greater than or equal to all elements of S?

Similarly, what is the greatest element of ℝ that is less than or equal to all the elements of *S*?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: ;

(a) For the least upper bound consider the following question: What is the supremum of the set $(-\infty,1)$?

(b) For the greatest lower bound consider the following question: What is the infimum of the set $(3,10]$?

Comment: From what you said, I am thinking that in a, b, & c, there is no least upper bound of the set $(-\infty,1)$, so each S does not have the greatest lower bound property.

Also, there is no infimum of the set $(3,10]$, but it exists in the second two Sets, so only the first set S does not have the least upper bound property. Is this correct?

Comment: @Michael I guess in your last sentence you mean "only the first set doesn't have the greatest lower bound property". Other than that everything you said is correct.

Comment: b is funny as it's just $S=(-\infty,1)\cup[2,10]$.